# Working with UTF-8 instead of windows-1255

Tags: database, url, encoding, utf-8

In the past, I used to work with windows-1255. Now my new page is written in UTF-8. When I send a query to DB (MS-Access), I get no results. The query on the URL shows the same like I type in by myself, but in this case (typing) I get results. How can it happen that I see the same URL on my IE and get the results and the other (that come from UTF-8) get no data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through is a useful read.

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing as ISO-1255. Are you sure you didn't mean Windows-1255? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255

Comment: Please point out which languages / platforms you are working with.

Comment: i work with ASP with DataBase Access 2003 (the data on DB is Windows-1255) the new page (ASP) work in format UTF-8

Comment: Are you getting back a resultset of no rows, or is the database returning some kind of error?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IE, try right-clicking in the page and checking the Encoding in both cases. Sometimes IE "auto detects" the encoding incorrectly, so any non-Ascii characters may be sent to the server encoded in a different way to how the server is decoding. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) may be useful in comparing what's being sent back and forth in both cases.